# Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so on fresh 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: php, mongodb

I installed a fresh image
updated and upgraded

`apt nginx-common php8.1-cli php8.1-fpm php8.1-mongodb`

`PHP -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' 
(tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so
(/usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: ns_parserr),
/usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so.so
(/usr/lib/php/20210902/mongodb.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) 
in Unknown on line 0
```

Why ?

How can I fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: One issue is the erroneous link to `mongodb.so.so`. In the PHP configuration files you'll want to figure out where `mongodb.so` is being referenced and confirm that it's following the proper declaration format. An additional `.so` will certainly result in a file not found error 

Comment: @matigo the path of the first try is correct `.../mongodb.so` (I can confirm there is a file) but then it follows a parse error. The way I interpret it: It found that file - load it but either it's corrupt or not for php8.1 then in a poorly executed attempt to recover from that error it builds a new path with the second ' .so`

Comment: This is absolutely murdering me, did you manage to resolve the issue in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I filed a bug report. if you could just  click on "This bug affects me" here -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php-mongodb/+bug/1992999